# VSAM to DB2 conversion - COBOL

Tags: db2, cobol, vsam

I'm trying to convert a vsam file to db2 table using load utility. However, one of my variables is pic s9(8)v99. When i try to load it into a column decimal(10,2) an error occurs - 02 invalid input numeric. Can you please help?

Comment: What is the usage, i.e., COMP-3, DISPLAY, something else...

Comment: Full message including any codes. Full JCL and control cards. Values for record failing, especially this field. Probably bad data.

Comment: Usage is DISPLAY.

Comment: This is an example of the number in a dump of the file VSAM: 

000004909è

Comment: In your LOAD statement, you may need to specify that field as DECIMAL ZONED (signed USAGE DISPLAY), as I see the presence of a sign in the last digit. If that works, please reply and I will create an answer for acceptance.

Comment: Yes, that was it!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

s9(8)v99 represents a signed variable to me. You may have to use char or varchar to store exact value with sign or try to absolute value.

Comment: A signed decimal (thus the V).

Comment: Correct . so while converting the sign to decimal(10,2) causing the problem ?

Comment: yes, the variable is signed. I've tried char but i need it to make calculations, and display  the number and it's incompatible with numeric pictures

Comment: use NUMERIC(10,2). Else you can do typecasting. By converting s9(8)v99 to string and then to decimal(10,2)